# Anchor tags / links does not work when using position: absolute; on my nav (I have a video in the background)

Tags: html, css, video, anchor, nav

I have a header with a video in the "background". On top of that I want to have a menu, when getting this to work my anchor tags/links stop working. How can I get this to work?

HTML

```
<nav class="menu">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">PRICES</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">CONTACT</a>
    </nav>

<div class="video-container">
      <video class="video-tablet" autoplay loop>
        <source src="videos/SampleVideo_720x480_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="videos/SampleVideo_720x480_1mb.webm" type="video/webm">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.video-tablet {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
    position: absolute;
}

.menu a {
     color: white;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: bold;
}

.menu a:hover {
     color: #559565;
}
```

Comment: did you try to set menu `z-index` attribute?

Comment: What do you mean it stops working? The href property doesn't point to anything, so obviously you don't mean redirection. Please elaborate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that your `video` is on the front of your navbar. So if you try to click on your navbar, you are actually clicking on the `video` that do nothing. To fix that you have to say that the navbar is on the front of the `video`. You can use for that `css` with the rule `z-index`:

```css
.video-tablet {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;      /* <-- Add a z-index value to .menu */
}

.menu a {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #559565;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">ABOUT</a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">PRICES</a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">CONTACT</a>
</nav>

<div class="video-container">
  <video class="video-tablet" autoplay loop>
    <source src="videos/SampleVideo_720x480_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="videos/SampleVideo_720x480_1mb.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```